# Using the word "aforementioned" in a sentence

Tags: single-word-requests

Would I be able to use "aforementioned time" in a sentence?

Comment: Only if you're a lawyer writing a legal document. Nobody else would write it, and no native speaker would ever **say** it, except for a joke.

Comment: The real question is: do you stress the *a* or the *fore*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be used, an example as follows:

> Apart from the **aforementioned time** characteristics of recorders, there is a need for yet another one, notably, threshold of response or measurement accuracy.

It is still used today from this NGram:

[image: NGram]

Comment: Thank you Daniil :)

Comment: Cheat! “Time characteristics” is not “time” and is horrible jargon, to boot. But why answer such a question?

Comment: @David *Apart from the **aforementioned time**, he'd never used an Ngram before.*